# Named imports from multiple sub-directories at once

Tags: python, python-import, directory-structure

Imagine I have the following structure:

```
├─ main.py
├─ stuff/
   ├─ more_stuff_one/
      ├── main.py
   ├─ more_stuff_two/
      ├── main.py
```

Right now, in `main.py` in the root folder, I am doing:

```
from stuff.more_stuff_one import main as more_stuff_one
from stuff.more_stuff_two import main as more_stuff_two
```

Is there a way to achieve the same result without having to explicitly go through each subfolder in `stuff`? I would like to import every `main.py` from each subfolder in `stuff` and name it like the subfolder.

Comment: Lets say we managed to import all at once. how are you going to use main.py? there are two `main.py` files, how are you going to differentiate between the two?

Comment: By giving each a unique alias (parent folder name). Or am I missing something?

Comment: you could use the __init__.py file from the parent folder. import inside of it the children. Then when using: `from stuff import more_stuff_one, more_stuff_two`

Answer (score -1):

you could use the `__init__.py` file from the parent folder. import inside of it the children.
You'd still have to go through the subfolders, but it will be 'hidden'

```
├─ main.py
├─ stuff/
   ├─ __init__.py
   ├─ more_stuff_one/
      ├── main.py
   ├─ more_stuff_two/
      ├── main.py
```

`__init__.py`'s contents:

```
from stuff.more_stuff_one import main as more_stuff_one
from stuff.more_stuff_two import main as more_stuff_two
```

usage from `main.py`:

```
from stuff import more_stuff_one, more_stuff_two
```

Comment: This is just shifting the imports from one file to another. What I'm after is *not having to explicitly import everything with an alias like that*. If anything, this adds more code to the total.